# Getting You need to define CIVICRM_DSN in civicrm.settings.php on backdrop

Tags: backdrop

Afternoon everyone,

I'm testing out Civicrm using backdrop and am getting the "You need to define CIVICRM_DSN in civicrm.settings.php" error. I decided to dig around in /modules/civicrm and noticed the file doesn't seem to exist. There is a template in /templates/crm/common. But it doesn't seem there is a working copy. Just to check I dug around the zipped file and it seems to have the same resultes. Any idea what's going on? Did the install fail or did backdrop not generate civicrm.settings.php during install?

Comment: The file is created by the civi installer - it sounds like it didn't run or failed. Were you following these docs? https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/backdrop/#installer

Comment: Yes I've tried that but clicking on the Civipanel just brings me to the CiviCRM  Installed screen. I can't seem to proceed and eventually I'll run into the DSN issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, but I'm not going to file one for you :-)

You need to create or fix the reference in civicrm.settings.php manually and edit it according to your server settings.

```
<?php
define('CIVICRM_SETTINGS_PATH', '<your server webroot joomla directory>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php');
$error = @include_once( '<your server webroot joomla directory>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' );
if ( $error == false ) {
    echo "Could not load the settings file at: /usr/www/users/helenmdfpt/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
";
    exit( );
}

// Load class loader
require_once $civicrm_root . '<your server webroot joomla directory>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
CRM_Core_ClassLoader::singleton()->register();
```